# Rails isolated engine model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-engines

I have an engine with a namespace 'shop'. Everything is great except that if I don't add the class_name: 'Shop::MyAssociatedModel' in association declarations I get errors.
For example product has many product_images
so if product model looks like this everything is ok:

```
module Shop
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_images, :class_name => 'Shop::ProductImage'
  end
end
```

In case I don't use class_name I get an error:

```
uninitialized constant ProductImage
```

On this line:

```
@products.in_groups_of(3) do |products|
  ...
```

This is my engine.rb file:

```
module Shop
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Shop
    ...
  end
end
```

The engine was created with rails generator on rails v 3.1.something and I upgraded to rails 3.2.5

Comment: do you have this in a public github repo? also normally class_name is not in a string it should be `Shop::ProductImage` not 'Shop::ProductImage' and you need to make sure you require product_image.rb within the engine.rb file (i think)

Comment: Sorry it is private (due to cleint's requirements). class_name should be string. You can see in rails documentation - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html and product_image.rb is a model located in app/models/shop/ so no need to require it. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: gah .. it was too late when I looked at this :( you're right! my apologies.

Comment: It can be `Shop::ProductImage` as well (`to_s` should be called implicitly)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Rails Guides - Engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#using-a-class-provided-by-the-application) section in the link, if you don't add the namespace, it will look for the class in the parent application's models, which is not what you want.